# TFS Automated Build with different platform

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am quite new to TFS Automated Build. I am having some issues to get automated build up and running.  Below is the detail..

I have a solution with 4 projects. 3 of them build on x86 and the 4th project build on Any CPU.

When I set up a new build definition, I configured the platform for x86 ( I am not sure if I can set up individually). Since the 4th project requires Any CPU, the build failed. The 4th project is a third party that we purchased with source code. Changing the 4th project to x86 causing millions of errors.

The question here is , how do I configure the build definition such that it knows the correct platform for each project. In other word, can I assign platform to a specific project individually?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Did you find a solution? I thought it builds active configuration but it doesn't seem to be doing that.

Comment: I got an update for the 4th project with x86. So it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

In the TFS build definition, change the platform from "x86" to "Mixed Platform". This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your solution file in Visual studio and click on "Solution Configuration". This will bring up the Solution COnfiguration manager, you can configure everything (configuration, platform, to build or not etc) that you have asked above here. Then within the build definition you can mention the specific tag you want it to be built.